# display pyramid of numbers

Tags: php, html

I Want to display number pyramids in this way where I am supossed to enter the number using form and I have to run the loop to display the number
       5
      45
     345
    2345
   12345
How can I do it in php please help me with this

Comment: At least make an effort to do your homework yourself before asking others to do it for you

Comment: `$numbers = '12345'; for($i = 1; $i <=5; $i++) echo substr($numbers, -$i);`

Comment: thanks  mark i'll try to make effort by myself before asking

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
for($i=5;$i>=1;$i--)
{
    for($j=$i;$j<=5;$j++)
    {
        echo $j ;
    }
    echo "<br>";

}


 //out put 
5
45
345
2345
12345
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $val = 5;
    for($i=$val;$i>=0;$i--)
    {
        for($j=$i;$j<=$val;$j++)
        echo $j;
        echo ' ';
    }
```